# Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception using android

Tags: android, mysql

I'm creating a simple crud system using android studio and mysql.I have added mysqlconnecter successfully. When I fill the form and click add an error is displayed. I've attached the screen shot image below.I don't know how to solve the problem.I have turned off the firewall as well.The code I have tried so far is attached below:

```
Sql failedjava.sql.SQLException: Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception: java.lang. ArraylndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2 
BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION 
java.lang. ArraylndexOutOfBounds Exception MESSAGE: length, ; index=2 
STACKTRACE: 
java.lang. ArraylndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2 at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer. readLong(Buffer.java:314) at com.mysql.jdbc.Mysq110. doHandshake(Mysq110.java:713) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection. createNew10(Connection.java:1808) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection. <ini,(Connection.java:452) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver. connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411) at java.sql.DriverManager. getConnection(DriverManager.java:175) at java.sql.DriverManager.
```

**Xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Name"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"


            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText ed1,ed2;
    Button b1;
    private static final String DBUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.100/basiccrud";
    private static final String User = "root";
    private static final String Pass = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed1 = findViewById(R.id.fname);
        ed2 = findViewById(R.id.lname);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Send objsend = new Send();
                objsend.execute("");
            }
        });
    }

    private class Send extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String msg="";
        String fname = ed1.getText().toString();
        String lname = ed2.getText().toString();
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.100/basiccrud","root","");
                if(conn==null)
                {
                      msg = "Connection Refusedddd";
                }
                else
                {
                    String query = "insert into record(firstname,lastname)values('" + fname +"','" + lname +"')";
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                    msg = "Record Adddedddd";
                }
                conn.close();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                msg = "Class failed" + e;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                msg = "Sql failed" + e;

                System.out.println(e);

            }
          return msg;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes sir. i found the error on sql failed sir. i attached the screen shot above

Comment: You have an IndexOutOfBoundsException before that.. Please post your error log as text not as a picture.

Comment: ok sir. ..................

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException how to solve it sir

Comment: i have added as a text error

Comment: You have an ArraylndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2 The 1 and 2 mean: The array has only one element. You are asking for element nr 2 which would be the third element. The first element has index==0. Well wherein your code does it go wrong? On which line?

Comment: sir can you correct the code sir

Comment: connection errrrr

Comment: That is no answer. Which line in your code causes the error?

Comment: Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.100/basiccrud","root",""); this line

Comment: If you have a host at TCP/IP address 192.0.0.1 with a host name of amrood, and your Oracle listener is configured to listen on port 1521, and your database name is EMP, then complete database URL would be −
jdbc:oracle:thin:@amrood:1521:EMP
Now you have to call getConnection() method with appropriate username and password to get a Connection object as follows −
String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@amrood:1521:EMP";
String USER = "username";
String PASS = "password"
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

Comment: See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm Does it apply?